# Find all records that have the same value in a field within a Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write an after insert trigger from table

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartsWork](
     [parts_work_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [experiment_id] [int] NOT NULL,
     [partition_id] [int] NULL,
     [sim_time] [time](7) NULL,
     [real_time] [datetime] NULL,
     [construction] [bit] NULL,
     [destruction] [bit] NULL,
     [part_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    )
```

I need to find out what is the how many rows have the same assembly_id as the inserted set.

assembly_id is a field in the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parts](
[part_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[part_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[part_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[assembly_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 )
```

I need to store that value as an int in a variable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You'd JOIN the special [INSERTED table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) (only available in triggers) to [dbo].[Parts] to get the COUNT.

Some thoughts:

- You have to consider multi-row inserts/updates in the trigger. You could have 2 assembly_ids for example
- When assigned to a variable, what do you want to do with it? The value won't be visible outside the trigger
- You may be better with a stored procedure for your processing and use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to get data back from the INSERT